# How can I persist resource data when my route changes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wiring up an AngularJS based [admin app template](http://themeforest.net/item/square-responsive-admin-app-with-angularjs/full_screen_preview/7511722) to an API. This is a snippet of what my navigation menu looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#/listings"><i class="fa fa-key"></i><span data-i18n="Listings"></span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/listings/active"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><span data-i18n="Active"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#/listings/need-photos"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><span data-i18n="Need Photos"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I have a main "Listings" page as well as two sub-pages of listings, which are just subsets of the main data set.

In my `listingCtrl`, I use a `Listing` resource that I created to fetch JSON data from an API. That data is then populated into my `$scope`. It's very easy to filter the data from within the controller, but the nav menu is outside of the `listingCtrl` scope.

This is the snippet of my listings controller that fetches the resource:

```
angular.module('app.listings', [])
.controller('listingCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$filter', '$location', 'Listing'
    ($scope, $filter, $location, Listing) ->

    # The listing controller checks the last segment of the URL
    # to determine which API call to place
    segments = $location.url().split('/')
    parameter = segments[segments.length-1]

    Listing.get({listingId: parameter}, (listings) ->
        $scope.listings = listings
    )
])
```

This is the configuration for my route provider for this specific page:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute'
])
.config([
    '$routeProvider'
    ($routeProvider) ->
        $routeProvider
            .when('/listings/:status?'
                templateUrl: 'views/listings/list.html'
            )
])
```

I was hoping that by specifying all of the `/listings` routes under one `when` method, it would prevent the controller from being reloaded when switching among those routes. That is apparently not the case.

I don't want to reload my `Listing` resource when switching among `/listings`, `/listings/active` and `/listings/need-photos`, although I do want the location hash to change. Currently, when I click on one of my nav links, it changes the hash and apparently the `$routeProvider` reloads the `templateUrl` and associated `listingCtrl`, which tosses my existing listing data and reloads it from the server. I would rather have the data persist and only the filter change when navigating among the three URLs.

How can I get my controller and router working together so that my REST resources aren't being reloaded when switching among the above routes?

Comment: A quick answer to that is use a *service* to bring *and cache* the data; let each view have its own controller, which will depend on the service to fetch the data; the service will decide whether to fetch from cache or call the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nikos is correct. You can make a service to hold a cache for your listings:

```
    app.factory('cacheExample', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory){
        return $cacheFactory('listingsData');
    }]);
```

Inject the service into your controller and use it to assign listings to the cache and refrain from making the API call if the listings have previously been cached. Should look something like:

```
    app.controller('listingCtrl', ['$scope', 'Listing', 'cacheExample', ($scope, 
    Listing, cacheExample){
        var listingsCache = cacheExample.get('listingsData');
        if(listingsCache){
            $scope.listings = listingsCache;
        }
        else{
            //the cache is empty, so make your API call with the Listing service 
            //and assign the result to the cache
            // ... other methods....
            Listing.get({listingId: parameter}, function(listings){
                $scope.listings = listings;
                cacheExample.put('listingsData', listings);
            });   
        }
    }]);
```

Alternatively, you can use the service as above, inject it into your controller, and use it with the cache option for $http:

```
    app.controller('ListingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'cacheExample', function($scope,
    $http, cacheExample){
        $http.get('/listingsUrl', {cache:  
        cacheExample}).success(function(response){
            $scope.listings = response;
        });
    }]);
```

Here is [a fiddle demonstrating the second case](http://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/LQuEU/). Note that if you use $http with the cache option, delivery of the data is asynchronous in the same way that real requests are, even if the response if served from your cache.